# NuxtJs - SSR - Webservice .Net

Tags: c#, web-services, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a Front application in NuxtJS-SSR; a webservice in .Net (Framework 4.8);
my app-front via axios makes a call on the webservice. this validates or invalidates the request by the IP connection obtained by System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses (HttpRequest.Request.UrlReferrer.Host);

The problem is that when I type the url of the front site directly in my browser or if my front site is deployed in Non-SSR, the webservice goes up without problem,
however if I use a search engine or a link from another site, the Front site in SSR mode returns the IP of the site that contains the url in the webservice, and not the IP of the site that contains my app-front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search on the Referrer side to specify a static url, which must be specified on the front side

https://javascript.info/fetch-api